# CUnit failures in hudson show success

Tags: c, unit-testing, hudson, cunit

i put unit tests in C running over hudson, but when i have a test that failures it shows a success in the build, but must to appear fail!

I'm using gcc to compile and run the executable in hudson like that:

```
gcc -lcunit test_ctesting.c -o testing
./testing
```

it's in a shell command, how can i get the failures and show it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CUnit XML to report your test result. Then use "Publish JUnit test result report" in Jenkins to show the result.

See CUnit automated for XML output: http://cunit.sourceforge.net/doc/running_tests.html#automated

Answer (score 1):

You can tell CUnit to run automated as Bjerking suggests.

It generates an Xml named CUnitAutomated-Results.xml at default.

This xml has to be transformed to be read from the "Publish JUnit test result report" task in Jenkins.

Steps:

- in your test program (ie test.c) call

  CU_automated_run_tests();
- Make and invoke your test program from Jenkins with a command like this:

  ./test
- Get [CUnit-to-JUnit transform](http://www.van-porten.de/2011/09/cunit-to-junit-transform-now-on-bitbucket/) and put it on your build machine
- Transform CUnitAutomated-Results.xml to Test-Result.xml using cunit-to-junit.xsl:

  xsltproc --novalid ../Build/cunit-to-junit.xsl CUnitAutomated-Results.xml > Test-Results.xml
- Add a "Publish JUnit test result report" task and point to:

  Test-Results.xml

Now when you build your project you get:

- SUCCESS if all tests are green
- UNSTABLE if you have one failure at least
- full Test Result Trend

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the CUnit example code does this:

```
   CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
   CU_basic_run_tests();
   CU_cleanup_registry();
   return CU_get_error();
```

I can't remember exactly what CU_get_error() returns right now, but it doesn't return a non-zero value if you've had tests fail. If you want to figure that out, you need to return the number of tests failed:

```
   unsigned int num_failures;
   CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
   CU_basic_run_tests();
   num_failures = CU_get_number_of_failures();
   CU_cleanup_registry();
   return num_failures;
```

I'm not sure how Hudson/Jenkins deals with this, but the non-zero return value will have CMake/CTest not report passed tests.

Answer (score -1):

The exit code is stored in the variable `$?`, and I'm assuming that if tests fail it's set to something non-zero.

... if it's something unixy, anyway.

Comment: I've tried print the $? variable, but it shows 0 to fails and success